# How to programmatically replace NA values in a dataframe with values in a list?

Tags: r

## Background

I am trying to impute missing values using the `library(mvnmle)` (ML Estimation for Multivariate Normal Data with Missing Values). Following is an example using the accompanying dataframe `apple` in the library:

```
data(apple)
mlest(apple)

$`muhat`
[1] 14.72227 49.33325

$sigmahat
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  89.53415 -90.69653
[2,] -90.69653 114.69470

$value
[1] 148.435

$gradient
[1]  4.988478e-06  2.892682e-06  8.726424e-07  1.682947e-05 -1.073488e-04

$stop.code
[1] 1

$iterations
[1] 34
```

## Question

There are few missing values in the `worms` column in the `apple` dataframe. `mlest` list provides `muhat` with mean values for both columns in the dataframe. I want to replace all the missing values in the `worm` column with the `muhat` value. In a different dataframe, there can be multiple columns with missing values. I want to programmatically replace all `NA` values with their corresponding values in the `muhat`.
In this example, I can manually do this by:

```
apple[is.na(apple2)] <- res$muhat[2]
```

How can I automate this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `tidyverse` packages? If so, I think this addresses your question and is scalable.

```
library(purrr)
res <- mlest(apple)

map2_df(apple,
        seq_along(apple),
        function(column, col_ind, mu_vec){
          if_else(is.na(column), mu_vec[col_ind], column)
        },
        res$muhat)
```

Answer (score 1):

using tidyverse:
first ensure the means are named according to the column names:

```
(mu=setNames(mlest(apple)$muhat,names(apple)))
    size    worms 
14.72227 49.33325
```

Now use `replace_na` to replace all the columns with the specific mean:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 apple%>%replace_na(as.list(mu))
```

In base R, you can use `sweep`:

```
 sweep(apple,2,mlest(apple)$muhat,function(x,y)replace(x,is.na(x),y[is.na(x)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question and data correctly, this should work.

```
apple$worms <- ifelse(is.na(apple$worms),res$muhat,apple$worms)
```